# use field value as a variable in sas

Tags: sas

Wonder if you can help me

I’ve got a dataset where the value in a column is also the field name of a column. I want to be able to use the value of the column to call the applicable field in a formula.

For instance … I have columns…

```
MERCH_NO
V01
M02
V08
M08
AMOUNT
PLAN
```

A record would look like this …and what I want the calc field to do…

```
MERCH_NO      V01   M02  V08  M08  AMOUNT    PLAN    CALC
123456        2     2    1    1    100.00    V01     value of V01 * AMOUNT
456789        4     4    4    4    250.00    M08     value of M08 * AMOUNT
```

If the **PLAN** field for a record says **V01**, then the value of the **V01** column must be used in the **CALC** field. If the **PLAN** field says, **M08**, then the **M08** value should be used. There are about 40 plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static example of how to use VVALUEX() function for that.

```
data result;
V01 = 2;
AMOUNT=100;
CALC = 'value of V01 * AMOUNT';
length arg1 arg2 $32;
arg1 = scan(compress(CALC, 'value of'), 1);
arg2 = scan(compress(CALC, 'value of'), 2);
put arg1 arg2;
result = input(VVALUEX(arg1), 16.) * input(VVALUEX(arg2), 16.);
run;
```

For your situation, you'd have to create logic to recognize all know patters of CALC, types and formats of variables (since `VVALUEX()` returns formatted values).

A dynamic approach but probably not suitable for lots of data is to generate the code for each row (see below).
Currently assumes a simple expression usable in `IF .. THEN`.

```
data input;
length CALC  $50;
input V01 M08 AMOUNT  CALC 9-58;
cards;
2 1 100 value of V01 * AMOUNT
2 4 100 value of M08 * AMOUNT
;
run;

/* code generation */
data _null_;
file 'mycalc.sas';
set input end=last;

length line $150;
if _N_=1 then do;
    put 'data result;';
    put '   set input;';
end;
line = 'if _N_ = ' || put(_N_, 8. -L) || 
         ' then RESULT = ' || compress(CALC, 'value of') || ';';
put line;
if last then put 'run;';
run;

%include 'mycalc.sas'; /* run the code */
```

Ok, now if see I didn't notice your note about PLAN field - please adjust as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Vasja's approach is the correct one - here is that approach using the PLAN variable as you describe.

```
data have;
input MERCH_NO      V01   M02  V08  M08  AMOUNT    PLAN $;
calc = input(vvaluex(plan),best12.) * amount;
put calc=;
datalines;
123456        2     2    1    1    100.00    V01     
456789        4     4    4    4    250.00    M08    
;;;;
run;
```

Comment: You guys are amazing!!!!! I got as far as VVALUEX, but just couldn't figure out how to apply it.